# Swift: Initializing an array of dictionaries, where the key is a String, and value is a type

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

I have an array which stores a dictionary. The dictionary has a `String` for a key, and a `Tuple` for the value. It looks like this:

`var mydict: [String: (key1: String, key2: String)]`

I want to initialize this array with a key, and an empty array for a value.

So like this:

`var mydict: [String: (key1: String, key2: String)] = ["dict_key1" : []]`

each time I try I get errors. any solutions?

Comment: You can't use an empty array as a value since it's specified as a tuple of two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize a tuple value with an array, because they're two different types. A tuple is a distinct type that has to contain the number of elements you specified for it to contain. So if you declare your dictionary as storing 2-element tuples, you have to store something in it with two elements. So you could initialize your dictionary with something like:

```
var mydict: [String: (key1: String, key2: String)] = ["dict_key1" : (key1: "", key2: "")]
```

However, if you want to store an array in the dictionary, I'd suggest you just type the dictionary as such:

```
var mydict: [String : [String]]
```

Comment: I want to store an array of tuples as the value, is this possible?

Comment: Sure, you can just type it as `[String : [(key1: String, key2: String)]]`.

Comment: You could, but if my guess as to what you're using this for is correct, you might find it more convenient just to initialize it to `[:]`, and then when you want to append something to the array you can just `mydict["dict_key1", default: []].append(...)`. Bet you didn't know you could do that. Swift is cool, ain't it?